# Twitter bootstrap and landscape ipad issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Twitter bootstrap in standard settings works like this:

```
0-767px mobile
768-991px tablet
992-1199 small desktop
1200 - infinite large desktop
```

My ipad works fine in portrait because its width is 768px but when i turn it into landscape (1024px) it's considered like a small desktop witch is not good.

The problem is that when i use a lansccape tablet i want to display one button type, and when i use the desktop (same width ~ 1024px) i want to display another button type. So both devices have the same width but one if tablet and one is pc, so i need to display diferent thing on them.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this post? It might be exactly what you're looking for (it was for me):
[Bootstrap Responsive layout hide nav on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221111/bootstrap-responsive-layout-hide-nav-on-ipad)